Anylogic-Problemas con librería de trafico
Tengo un problema en anylogic. Usé la librería de trafico para simular la situación actual de un cuadrante limitado de calles, para esto se usó eventos discretos, por lo que la decisión de que el auto vire en una dirección u otra es en base a una probabilidad, la cual va cambiando cada 15 minutos (por la toma de datos). Ejemplo abajo.
Como esto es una simulación de trafico, esta lógica esta conectada a un modelo 2D o mapa (Que no es el GIS).
Cree 2 variables para revisar el conteo de los autos que pasaban, es decir, puse un contador en la stopLine de una calle y al mismo tiempo en "on exit" del CarMoveTo referente a la misma calle, y viendo ese contador más el comportamiento del mapa, al comparar la cantidad no concuerdan. En otras palabras, el mapa me muestra que han pasado 4 vehículos mientras que el lógico ( en el mismo tiempo) me muestra que han pasado solo 2 y no sé bien por qué puede ser. Ayuda por favor, es para terminar mi proyecto de titulo :(
time(MINUTE) <= 30 ? random() < 0.90 : (
time(MINUTE) <= 45 ? random() < 0.85 : (
time(MINUTE) <= 60 ? random() < 0.88 : (
time(MINUTE) <= 75 ? random() < 0.89 : (
time(MINUTE) <= 90 ? random() < 0.84 : (
time(MINUTE) <= 105 ? random() < 0.82 : random() < 0.77))))))```


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Esto es js, java o que cosa??? no conozco la herramienta esa, la google y no se en que se programa. Si no pones las etiquetas que corresponden, nadie te va a poder contestar...

Creo que vendría bien un [mcve] y poner las etiquetas relevantes.
